# What's the difference between these 2 SQL Server XQuery queries?

Tags: sql-server, xquery

We have a column in a table that contains xml and is setup as a non-schema based xml column

The data can contain multiples instance of a node that looks like this:

```
<eq:Fund>
  <v:FundCode>
    <v:type>SEDOL</v:type>
    <v:value>3049141</v:value>
  </v:FundCode>
</eq:Fund>
<eq:Fund>
  <v:FundCode>
    <v:type>Product Provider Specific</v:type>
    <v:value>CASH</v:value>
  </v:FundCode>
</eq:Fund>
```

This query returns 448 rows:

```
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schema1' as eq, 'http://schema2' as v, DEFAULT 'http://schema3')
select * from xml_request
WHERE xml_request_body.value('contains( string( (//v:type)[1] ),"SEDOL")','bit') = 1
```

This query returns 784 rows (after removing blanks in the result column)

```
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schema1' as eq, 'http://schema2' as v, DEFAULT 'http://schema3')
select xml_request.xml_request_ser, xml_request.agency_number, xml_request.policy_holder, xml_request.product,
xml_request_body.query('for $x in /eq:EQuote/eq:Request/eq:Fund where $x/v:FundCode/v:type = "SEDOL" return $x') as result
from xml_request
```

1) Why do they return different number of rows? The first query doesn't find all the rows where the element contains SEDOL? Why not?

I'm guessing it may be due to the fact that the element with SEDOL may not be the first? 2) How do I change the first query to look through all elements not just the first?

Comment: First expression is a **boolean** expression. So, it doesn't select any node by itself. You are using some specific  SLQ-Server method defining the evaluation context of this boolean expression. The second is a `FLOWR` expression that speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[1]` in the first means that it explicitly requires the *first* `type` element (in document order) to contain `SEDOL`, in order for a match to be made. So yes, if as you say some rows have a non-SEDOL `FundCode` first, they won't match.

What you want to do it the first way is

```
WHERE xml_request_body.exist('//v:type[contains(., "SEDOL")]') = 1
```

This looks for *any* `v:type` element such that the text contains SEDOL.